# Logic Synthesis Synthesis - Consensus property?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

OK, I'm working on a synthesis problem that doesn't quite make sense. I start with the equation \$f = x_1x_2'x_3' + x_1x_2x_4 + x_1x_2'x_3x_4'\$ and have to reduce it but I keep going in loops. I tried the solution from the solution from the Solutions Manual but one line doesn't make sense. They go from

---

\$x_1x_2'x_3'x_4' + x_1x_2'x_3'x_4 + x_1x_2x_4 + x_1x_2'x_3x_4'\$

---

to

---

\$x_1x_2'x_3' + x_1x_2'(x_3' + x_3)x_4' + x_1x_2x_4\$

---

I understand what they've done to combine the 1st and 4th products (and moved the 3rd product to the end), but what happened to the \$x_4'\$ on the second term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$x_1x_2'x_3'x_4' + x_1x_2'x_3'x_4 + x_1x_2x_4 + x_1x_2'x_3x_4'\$

Repeating first term : a = a+a

\$x_1x_2'x_3'x_4' + x_1x_2'x_3'x_4' + x_1x_2'x_3'x_4 + x_1x_2x_4 + x_1x_2'x_3x_4'\$

Associativity :

\$x_1x_2'x_3'x_4' + x_1x_2'x_3'x_4 + x_1x_2'x_3'x_4' + x_1x_2'x_3x_4' + x_1x_2x_4\$

=
\$x_1x_2'x_3'(x_4' + x_4) + x_1x_2'(x_3' + x_3)x_4' +  x_1x_2x_4\$

Simplification : a + a' = 1

\$x_1x_2'x_3' + x_1x_2'x_4' + x_1x_2x_4\$

Comment: Makes perfect sense when you write that, my solutions manual just skips random steps. Thank you!